# Statements about differentiation

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

> Let $f:(a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,b). Suppose the limit $\lim_{x \to b-}f'(x)$ exists.Prove $f$ is differentiable from the left at $b$.

Now does this proof incoprorate mean value theorem, if $$\lim_{x \to b-}f'(x)$$ then this is the same as :  =$$\lim_{x \to b-}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ where $x \in (a,b)$ is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the mean value theorem,
$$\dfrac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}=f'(c_x)$$
for some $c_x$ between $x$ and $b$.
If $x\to b^-$. then $c_x\to b^-$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to b^-}\dfrac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}=
\lim_{x\to b^-}f'(c_x)=\lim_{x \to b^-}f'(x)
$$